# How to quickly/easily merge and average data in matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, simulink

I have got a matrix of AirFuelRatio values at certain engine speeds and throttlepositions. (eg. the AFR is 14 at 2500rpm and 60% throttle)
The matrix is now 25x10, and the engine speed ranges from 1200-6000rpm with interval 200rpm, the throttle range from 0.1-1 with interval 0.1.

Say i have measured new values, eg. an AFR of 13.5 at 2138rpm and 74,3% throttle, how do i merge that in the matrix? The matrix closest values are 2000 or 2200rpm and 70 or 80% throttle. Also i **don't** want new data to **replace** the older data. How can i make the matrix take this value in and adjust its values to take the new value in account?

Simplified i have the following x-axis values(top row) and 1x4 matrix(below):

`2  4  6  8
14 16 18 20`

I just measured an AFR value of 15.5 at 3 rpm. If you interpolate the AFR matrix you would've gotten a 15, so this value is out of the ordinary.
I want the matrix to take this data and adjust the other variables to it, ie. average everything so that the more data i put in the more reliable and accurate the matrix becomes. So in the simplified case the matrix would become something like:

`2    4    6    8
14.3 16.3 18.2 20.1`

So it averages between old and new data. I've read the documentation about concatenation but i believe my problem can't be solved with that function.

EDIT: To clarify my question, the following visual clarification.
[image]
The 'matrix' keeps the same size of 5 points whil a new data point is added. It takes the new data in account and adjusts the matrix accordingly. This is what i'm trying to achieve. The more scatterd data i get, the more accurate the matrix becomes. (and yes the green dot in this case would be an outlier, but it explains my case)

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

This is not a matter of simple merge/average. I don't think there's a quick method to do this unless you have simplifying assumptions. What you want is a statistical inference of the underlying trend. I suggest using Gaussian process regression to solve this problem. There's a great MATLAB toolbox by Rasmussen and Williams called GPML. http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/

Comment: It appears to be able to do what i want, ie. averaging scattered data into one matrix. I hope i'll be able to use it, it looks rather complex and i'm still an engineer in education. i'll look into it and mark your reply as answer if it works for me, thx

Answer (score 2):

This sounds more like a data fitting task to me.  What you are suggesting is that you have a set of measurements for which you wish to get the best linear fit.  Instead of producing a table of data, what you need is a table of values, and then find the best fit to those values.  So, for example, I could create a matrix, A, which has all of the recorded values.  Let's start with:

```
A=[2,14;3,15.5;4,16;6,18;8,20];
```

I now need a matrix of points for the inputs to my fitting curve (which, in this instance, lets assume it is linear, so is the set of values 1 and x)

```
B=[ones(size(A,1),1), A(:,1)];
```

We can find the linear fit parameters (where it cuts the y-axis and the gradient) using:

```
B\A(:,2)
```

Or, if you want the points that the line goes through for the values of x:

```
B*(B\A(:,2))
```

This results in the points:

```
2,14.1897   3,15.1552   4,16.1207   6,18.0517   8,19.9828
```

which represents the best fit line through these points.

You can manually extend this to polynomial fitting if you want, or you can use the Matlab function `polyfit`.  To manually extend the process you should use a revised `B` matrix.  You can also produce only a specified set of points in the last line.  The complete code would then be:

```
% Original measurements - could be read in from a file,
% but for this example we will set it to a matrix
% Note that not all tabulated values need to be present
A=[2,14; 3,15.5; 4,16; 5,17; 8,20];

% Now create the polynomial values of x corresponding to
% the data points.  Choosing a second order polynomial...
B=[ones(size(A,1),1), A(:,1), A(:,1).^2];

% Find the polynomial coefficients for the best fit curve
coeffs=B\A(:,2);

% Now generate a table of values at specific points
% First define the x-values
tabinds = 2:2:8;
% Then generate the polynomial values of x
tabpolys=[ones(length(tabinds),1), tabinds', (tabinds').^2];
% Finally, multiply by the coefficients found
curve_table = [tabinds', tabpolys*coeffs];
% and display the results
disp(curve_table);
```

Comment: this creates a filtered version of the existing matrix right? Or it fits a curve to it. but that's not what my aim is. i need to add more data to the matrix, so it averages with that new data, while the size of the matrix stays the same.

Comment: If you are adding data to the matrix, I'm not sure how it is going to remain the same size!  If you only wish to tabulate the values for 2,4,6,8, etc., but allow these values to be adjusted by underlying data, then you are essentially fitting to the expanded matrix, but in the last line what you should do is instead of multiplying the coefficients by B, create a new matrix, `tabvals=[ones(1,4), (2:2:8)'];` then use `tabvals*(B\A(:,2))` to get only the tabulated values on the regular grid you've specified.  Is this what you are after?

Comment: I should add that if all you store are the final tabulated values, then you've got some problems.  How do you know in what way to adjust the table when a new value comes along.  In your example, why didn't you simply add 0.5 to all values?  What happens if you have one outlier, but all of the rest of the data is good.  Without storing data, or at least statistical information on that data, you've really got no other basis on which to adjust the table.  That's why I was suggesting storing of measurement data, and then taking the best linear fit to that data.

Comment: Thanks for your help and effort. I don't quite know how to explain it, so i'll post a visual clarification in my original question. Im collecting more and more (scattered)data, but i want to keep de matrix, that i approximated the trend of the data with, the same size. ie. the matrix itself shouldn't get larger.The picture in my post shows a 'matrix' of 5 data points, which is based on say, 10 measured, scattered, data points. Now i measured a new one, the green one, and i want the matrix to adjust to that. like the red line.

Comment: @Bart, if this is the case, then my comment above should be useful.  You should store *all* of your measurements in A, recompute the best linear fit using `B\A(:,2)`, then present results for your specified datapoints, the x-coordinates of which are in `tabvals`.  Your curve suggests that a linear fit isn't going to be sufficient, so I'll revise my original post to include a quadratic fit.

Comment: Thankyou! I'll look into it, and try if i can make it work. If i can i'll come back to mark your post as the answer.